# how to change PyTorch maxpool (ceil mode) in TensorFlow 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, tensorflow2.0, max-pooling

```
self.pool3 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, ceil_mode=True)  # ceiling (not floor) here for even dims
```

How to change PyTorch's ceil_mode=True in TensorFlow 2.0?

Comment: wait, what? What do you mean by change one framework parameter in another?

Comment: pytorch -> tensorlfow2.0 . I'm tryint to change the pytorch to tensorflow.